# Integrability of functions $ f,g \in R([a,b]) $ when $ A \subseteq [a,b] $ is a dense set s.t. $ f|_{A} = g|_{A} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

**Theorem:** Let $ f,g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ s.t. $ f,g, \in R([a,b]) $. Let $ A \subseteq [a,b] $ be a dense set. Suppose for all $ x \in A $, $f(x) = g(x)$. Then $  \int_{a}^{b} f  = \int_{a}^{b} g $.

**Proof from lecture notes:**
We'll chose a sequence of partitions $ \{ \prod_n \}_{n=1} $ with $ \lambda(\prod_n) \rightarrow 0 $. For every such partition $ \prod_n $ we'll chose a finite sequence of appropriate points $ \{ t_i^{(n)} \}_{i=1}^{m_n} $ where $ m_n $ is the number of points in partition $ \prod_n $, for every $ n $. Also $ t_i^{(n)} \in A $ for every $ i ,n $.
We have that $\forall n. S(f,\prod_n,\{ t_i^{(n)} \}_{i=1}^{m_n}) = S(g,\prod_n,\{ t_i^{(n)} \}_{i=1}^{m_n} ) $ and that is because $ f|_{A} = g|_{A} $. As $ n \rightarrow \infty $ we'll get  $  \int_{a}^{b} f  = \int_{a}^{b} g $

**Questions:**

1. Can you give an example of a choice of sequence of partitions $ \{ \prod_n \}_{n=1} $ with $ \lambda(\prod_n) \rightarrow 0 $?
2. Can you give an example of a choice of finite sequence of appropriate points $ \{ t_i^{(n)} \}_{i=1}^{m_n} $  of partition $ \prod_n $, for every $ n $  ( s.t.  $ t_i^{(n)} \in A $ for every $ i,n $ ) ?
3. In the proof , why do I need the condition that $A \subseteq [a,b]$ is a dense set ? I can't quite see how the fact that it's dense is used in the proof.

****Notes about notation:****

- $ f \in R([a,b]) $ means $ f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b] $ .
- ( mesh of partition ) $ \lambda(\prod _n) = max_{i=1,...,M_n}|{ \triangle x_i}| $ , where $ x_i  \in \prod_n $, for all $ 1 \leq i \leq M_n $, where $ M_n $ is the number of points in the partition.
- ( Riemann sum ) given $ f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a partition $ \prod $ and finite sequence of approproiate numbers $ \{ t_i \} $, their Riemann sum is defined as:  $S\left(f, \Pi,\left\{t_{i}\right\}\right)=\sum_{i} f\left(t_{i}\right) \Delta x_{i}$
- ( finite sequence of appropriate numbers ) Given a partition $ \prod = ( x_0,...,x_l ) $, we'll say $ \{ t_1,...,t_l \} $ are appropriate points for the partition if it occurs that $t_i \in [ x_{i-1} , x_i] $ for all $ i = 1,...,n $
- ( Reminder for dense sets: ) Let $ I \subset \mathbb{R} $ be an interval  ( finite or not ).  set $ A \subset I $ will be called dense in $ I $ if for every open interval $ J \subseteq I $ it occurs that $ A \cap J \neq \emptyset $

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Without density of $A$, how would you know every subinterval of the partition contains a point from $A$? Density is very important here. As for an example, try to take $\Pi_n$ to be a partition of $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals of the same length. Each subinterval of $\Pi_n$ contains a rational point. (because $\mathbb{Q}\cap [a,b]$ is dense in $[a,b]$)

Comment: So the fact that $  A $ is dense will allow me to take points take belong to $ A $, meaning I can create a partition $ \prod_n $ for $ [a,b] $ such that every point in the partition will belong to $ A $, hence I can make both $f,g $ be integrable over $ [a,b ] $ using the fact $  f|_{A} = g|_{A} $

Comment: The fact that $A$ is dense allows you to choose points from $A$ in any partition. And note that you assume that $f$ and $g$ are integrable, this is very important here. It's not true that if $f$ and $g$ agree on a dense set and one of them is integrable then the other function is integrable as well. For example, the Dirichlet function agrees on a dense subset with the constant function $0$, but it is not integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $[a,b] = [0,1]$ you obviously want to consider $t_i^{(n)} = \frac i n$ and let $i$ going from $0$ to $n$. For general $a$ and $b$ just take $t_i^{(n)} = a + i \frac {b-a}{n}$.
2. Take any sequence of positive real numbers $\lambda_n$ that vanishes at $+ \infty$. Take $(t_i^{(n)})$ the mesh defined in point 1. For any $i,n$, by density of $A$,
   $$ A \cap ] t_i^n - \lambda_n , t_i^n + \lambda_n [ \cap [a,b]\neq \emptyset.$$
   Then call $x_i^n$ an element of this set,
   $$ |x_{i+1}^n - x_i^n| \leq |x_{i+1}^n - t_{i+1}^n| + |t_{i+1}^n - t_i^n| + |t_i^n - x_i^n| < 2 * \lambda_n +  \frac 1 n  $$
   so the mesh $(x_i^{(n)})$ mesh goes to $0$.
3. As you saw in point 2. we need density. Without it just take $A = \emptyset$. To see why it works, prove that if $f,g$ are continuous and equal on $A$ then $f=g$.

Comment: ( Regarding 3: ) What if $ f,g $ are not continuous on $ A $? what if they are step functions ( that are integrable ), if so, will I still have that $ f = g $?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 Of course no : $[a,b] = [0,1]$, $A = [0,1[$, $f = 1$ and $g = 1_{[0,1/2[} + 1_{[1/2,1[}$.